# How to pass an incremental index value to $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I pass an incremental value into the $http.get function. See below for code snippet:

```
for($scope.index=0 ; $scope.index < 5 ; $scope.index++)

        {
            $http.get('/api/post', {params: { id: $scope.userActivity[$scope.index].post }})
                .success(function(res){
                    console.log('The value for index is: ' + $scope.userActivity[$scope.index]);
                })
                .error(function(data, status){
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        })
```

I am getting "The value for index is: **undefined**" and it is driving me nuts!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by the time your first (and in fact all) your `success` callbacks fire `$scope.index` will have the value `5` which is presumably outside of the range of `$scope.userActivity` array.

One way to solve this is to use an IIFE

```
for($scope.index=0 ; $scope.index < 5 ; $scope.index++)

    {
      (function(i){
        $http.get('/api/post', {params: { id: $scope.userActivity[i].post }})
            .success(function(res){
                console.log('The value for index is: ' + $scope.userActivity[i]);
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
      })
    })($scope.index);
  }
```

This other StackOverflow Q/A will give you more in-depth detail: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2):

`Closures` to rescue, your `index` which is not in sync with the with `$scope.userActivity`

```
for ($scope.index = 0; $scope.index < 5; $scope.index++){
    (function(i) {
        $http.get('/api/post', {
                params: {
                    id: $scope.userActivity[$scope.index].post
                }
            })
            .success(function(res) {
                console.log('The value for index is: ' + $scope.userActivity[$scope.index]);
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }($scope.index))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. As I said in the comment above, it did the trick. Highly appreciated